# Which to choose: relations with a non Jewish woman or wasting seed

Tags: halacha, sexuality, priorities

If a man had to choose, which should he choose: relations with a non Jewish woman or wasting seed?

Someone told me that he was taught that relations with a non Jewish woman should be chosen (that is what his Rabbi taught him).

But I can not find anything on this subject

Is he correct? 
Source please

Comment: neither, how is that a choice a ben Torah should be making?

Comment: @Dude is there not a tosfois Regarding temptation that you can not control,

Comment: not familiar with that tosfor. one of the big things which makes a person different from an animal is the ability to control impulses and desires

Comment: @Dude See http://www.torahmusings.com/2013/07/what-to-wear-to-a-sin/

Comment: A shut haRivash, I need to find it.

Comment: Doesn't relations with a non Jewish woman include the aveira of waiting seed?

Comment: Be'er Moshe has a tshuva like this, he was asked what's worse, sleeping with a single Jewish girl who went to the mikvah or sleeping with a nonjewish girl. He refused to answer because he was afraid the asker was just going to try to make himself feel better by choosing the lesser of two evils. The asker wrote back to say that was indeed the case and the fact that the Rabbi refused to answer him helped get the message across and he did not in fact sin.

Comment: I find it disappointing how many down-votes are given to a question that is addressed by the Poskim (at least tangentially). The down-vote isn't there for you to make a political statement.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu A question that a Poseik addresses is not the same thing as a good question for our site. Your comment shows you misunderstand how this site works, even as you are correct about one reason not being a motivating factor for the existence of downvotes.

Comment: see parsha Pinchas. seems relations with nonjew is has an aspect of being a capital offense. no such thing by motzi zera

Comment: @hazoriz the tosfot you mentionned is in [Chagiga 16a](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_daf.php?ms=Chagigah&df=16a)

Comment: @user6591 do you know the source of that Beer Moshe please?

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has yet cited the Gemara in Chagigah: if a person is going to sin anyhow, do it in a way that minimizes the desecration to G-d's reputation.

Comment: @Avraham Sorry, not offhand.

Comment: @Shalom isn't it a machlokes Rabbeinu Chananel and Tosafos whether to take that gemara at face value? Tosafos assumed the point was that after going through those steps, a person would not in fact sin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This topic is largely treated in Talmudic books.

#### We are going to start with a Mishna in Sanhedrin 9, 6

> וְהַבּוֹעֵל אֲרַמִּית, קַנָּאִין פּוֹגְעִין בּוֹ .‏
>
> <sup>Or cohabits with a heathen [lit. syrian {Aramean}] woman, he is punished by zealots.</sup>

One see that in some circumstances, not treated in this post, man involved in intimate relation with a non-Jewish women is punishable by zealots. If he is punishable, one can assume that he broke the law. So what is the problem for a Jewish man who is involved in intimate relationship with a non-Jewish woman? Bartenura said:

> אֲבָל עָנְשׁוֹ מְפֹרָשׁ עַל פִּי נָבִיא, יַכְרֵת ה' לָאִישׁ אֲשֶׁר יַעֲשֶׂנָּה. וּמַלְקִין אוֹתוֹ אַרְבַּע מַלְקֻיּוֹת מִדִּבְרֵי סוֹפְרִים, מִשּׁוּם נִדָּה, מִשּׁוּם שִׁפְחָה מִשּׁוּם נָכְרִית, מִשּׁוּם זוֹנָה‏
>
> <sup>His punishment was spelled out in the book of Malachi (Mal'achi 2, 12): "May the LORD cut off to the man that doeth this", and we punish him by four flagellations for rabbinic prohibitions: Nidda, Slave, Stranger, Prostitute (if he is Cohen),</sup>

It's seems not current to find a "Kareth" in Prophet book that is not found in Pentateuch. In Gemara, we see that Amorayim have great difficulties getting a verse for the prohibition. As summarized in the Bartenura, the standing hypothesis is the verse in Mal'achi. The Rabbinical Prohibition entered into force on a Rabbinical Court at time of Chashmonaym. There are four rabbinical prohibitions whose initials are 'נשג"ז' (N.Sh.G.Z.).

#### We shall proceed to consider Halacha. Firstly Rambam

I will try to select only the parts of the Halacha treating a kind of relationship based on sexual drive only, without any cohabitation contract.
The begining of the 12<sup>th</sup> chapter of Hilchot Issure Biah.

#### Look only on bold characters

> *Halacha 2*
>
> **The Scriptural prohibition applies only to marital relations**. When, by contrast, one engages in **relations with a gentile woman with a licentious intent, he is given "stripes for rebellious conduct" according to Rabbinic Law**. [This is a] decree,
>
> ### lest this lead to marriage.
>
> If [a Jew] designates [a gentile woman] for licentious relations, he is liable for relations with a niddah, a maid-servant, a gentile woman, and a licentious woman. **If he did not designate her for himself, but instead, [engage in relations with her] spontaneously, he is only liable for relations with a gentile woman. All of these liabilities are Rabbinic in origin**.
>
> *Halacha 6*
>
> ... **a person who shares intimacy with a gentile woman is considered as if he married a false deity**, as the verse states: "engaging in relations with **the daughter of a foreign god**." And he is called one who "desecrated that which is sacred to God."
>
> *Halacha 7*
>
> Although this transgression is not punishable by death penalty by the court, it should not be regarded lightly, for **it leads to a detriment that has no parallel among all the other forbidden sexual relationships**....
>
> *Halacha 8*
>
> This matter causes one **to cling to the gentile nation** from whom the Holy One, blessed be He, has separated us, and to turn away from following God and to betray Him.

There's a strong contrast between the lightness of the sin and the severity of consequences. Rambam explains clearly that the problem is the risk for this open relationship to result in a marriage. Each of us is aware of cases. Cases are frequent. This is described as leading to a detriment that has no parallel among forbidden sexual relations. The message is that this is a trap. All intimate relation of this kind lead potentially to assimilation. The Shulchan Aruch E.H., [1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71266/which-to-choose-relations-with-a-non-jewish-woman-or-wasting-seed), [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71266/which-to-choose-relations-with-a-non-Jewish-woman-or-wasting-seed) is similar.

#### The problem of wasting seed.

> #### Gemara Nidda 13a
>
> דא"ר יוחנן: כל המוציא שכבת זרע לבטלה 
> **‏
> חייב מיתה,**
> ‏
>  שנאמר (בראשית ל"ח) וירע בעיני ה' (את) אשר עשה וימת גם אותו.
>
> רבי יצחק ורבי אמי אמרי: כאילו שופך דמים שנאמר (ישעיהו נ"ז) הנחמים באלים תחת כל עץ רענן שוחטי הילדים בנחלים תחת סעיפי הסלעים, אל תקרי שוחטי אלא סוחטי.
>
> רב אסי אמר: כאילו עובד עבודת כוכבים, כתיב הכא תחת כל עץ רענן וכתיב התם (דברים יב) על ההרים הרמים ותחת כל עץ רענן.‏
>
> #### A verse was put in evidence, Genesis 38, 10:
>
> וַיֵּ֛רַע בְּעֵינֵ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה אֲשֶׁ֣ר עָשָׂ֑ה וַיָּ֖מֶת גַּם-אֹתֽוֹ:‏
> And the thing which he did displeased the Lord; therefore he slew him also.
>  *After first reading, I would argue that the problem is **Contraception**. He opted for marital relations without "reproduction". Chazal explain that he used the method called nowadays "Withdrawal method". This method has two consequences: Avoid insemination, extra-corporeal ejaculation ("on tree and rock").*

#### Contextualization after contextualization

At beginning, Gemara is commenting the sentence of Mishna "Every hand that makes frequent examination in the case of men it ought to be cut off". It is against this background that we must view the sentence of Rabbi Yochanan. Nothing to do with contraception.  Rambam  Issure Bia 21, 18, [**HERE**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=52511&rid=4517)
reports this sentence on halachot. And in the next sentence he address an other issue, marrying a prepubescent wife:

> It is forbidden to release sperm wastefully. Therefore a person should not enter his wife and ejaculate outside of her. A man should not marry a minor who is not fit to give birth.
>
> Those who, however, release sperm with their hands, beyond the fact that they commit a great transgression...

See [Mesharet Moshe](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=45026&rid=4517). He said that poskim made a difference between wasting seed and spousing a non-fertile wife: The second is only an annulment of Mitsvat Piria Verivia.

See Rambam. See in Sefer Nishmat Avraham EH 23 in name of R.S.Z. Aurbach that obviously Rambam and Rabenu Tam  do not consider this sin as Scriptural, and so there is no Macat Mardut. But Rabbi Moshe Feinstein does not agree and considers it as a Scriptural Sin.

To see the problem as a choice between two averot is perhaps not a real problem. *To make a sin can not protect against another (the case in Sefer Chassidim is a rare exception for short term resolution). **We can say without missing that a man involved in relations with non Jewish women is more dangerous for future, less prohibited for present.***

Comment: Please tell me when you Finnish (and if you find the shut harivash

Comment: @kouty This answer could be greatly improved by making it more concise, properly spaced and written with better English grammar. I apologize if English is not one of your strongest languages; but, it is the chief language of this site.

Comment: You might be interested 1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HTxEO.jpg
 2: http://i.stack.imgur.com/U0z7F.jpg
 3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dCXAC.jpg
4 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/nR2Ro.jpg
5 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/wG3hL.jpg

Comment: @hazoriz For posterity's sake, you're better off finding Sefer Hasidim on a site like HebrewBooks and providing links to the appropriate pages (IMGUR doesn't store images forever). For readability's sake, please consider using [markdown](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) (see the previous word, "markdown", for an example).

Comment: 6: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GWzLd.jpg

Comment: @Lee what should I do if it is not on Hebrewbooks?

Comment: @hazoriz If I'm not mistaken, it **is** on HebrewBooks [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52176&st=&pgnum=60). If it's not available on HB, try Googling for another, more permanent, electronic source other than IMGUR. If it's not available anywhere, I personally just cite the name of the book and the location within the book of the citation (e.g. "Darke'i Taharah, Chapter 3, Section 4").

Comment: @Lee it does not have the comenteries that I brought

Comment: @hazoriz See my comment above for what I do in that case (as has been done for thousands of years before electronic copies were readily available).

Comment: None of this answers the question. It should be a comment; not an answer. All we see is that there is no probably no biblical prohibition with either. Which one is preferable, however, is not clarified.

Comment: @mevaqesh but you can see an allusion to answer. I do not give answer because I am not sure that there is a such reality of this 2 possibilities as the only 2.

Comment: @kouty Simple. You have a gun to your head and are told that unless you perform one of these two activities you will be killed.

Comment: ein kishui ela ledaat?

Comment: @kouty You said, 'All intimate relation of this kind lead potentially to assimilation.' That is never the case, if the woman is a prostitute.

Comment: @Nars Sojourner I know people who eventually married their preferred prostitute.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is lechalach, especially since it expresses both as very bad in different ways, but the tanya certainly describes this at the end of chapter 7:

He explains that zera levatala is in one regard worse, because quantitatively, a person who sins such brings many more klipot ("bad forces") into the word than by forbidden relations.

Nevertheless, qualitatively, forbidden relations are worse in that (as explained by the Rebbe in a note) when one sins as such, by being with a woman he contributes vitality to a klipa, the female aspect of yesod. By zera levatala there is nothing to absorb vitality in the same way. Therefore, the level of teshuva required for forbidden relations is much higher than for zera levatala (because he must re-raise up the vitality that was absorbed).

Thus, on a basic level zera levatala is worse, but in another aspect forbidden relations are worse.

Honestly, I don't quite understand the above, except that both are quite bad, zera levatala worse on its own, except that the fact you are with a woman in the other case adds an extra level of polluting effect to that.

Comment: Assuming of course that non Jew falls under the same category as forbidden relationship, which I'm not sure about. But this as least gives you and idea.

Comment: It's... difficult to discuss halachic ranking by bringing in a source that deals in metaphysics, not halacha. If you were to quote the Shulchan Aruch HaRav, for  instance, as evidence of a ruling by the mesorah of the Ba'al HaTanya, that would make for a more substantive argument.

Comment: @Isaac Question was not restricted to halakha and site's scope is "Jewish law and tradition"

Answer (score 3):

If a man is in a situation where he is tempted by one of the Arayos (e.g. a married woman or a niddah) and he knows that he can withstand the temptation if he were to be motzi zera, a number of sources say that it is preferable for the man to be motzi zera.

The [Bais Shmuel to Shulchan Aruch, Even Ha'ezer 23:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.23.1?lang=he&p2=Beit_Shmuel.23.1&lang2=he), cites the Sefer Chasidim for this ruling and appears to hold that this permitted because intercourse with arayos is a more severe prohibition.  The Chelkas Mechokek and the Be'er Heitev give the same reason.

But the [Chochmas Shlomo](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.23.1?lang=he&p2=Chokhmat_Shlomo_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.23.1&lang2=he) gives a different explanation for the heter.  He argues that if the reason a person is being motzi zera is to prevent himself from violating a prohibition, then the hotzoas zera is not levatala. The man isn't wasting seed, he is using for the positive purpose of refraining from sin.

I think that the answer to your question depends on whether the halacha follows the Bais Shmuel or the Chochmas Shlomo. According to the Bais Shmuel it is likely that the man should not waste seed because hotzas zera l'vatala is a severe biblical prohibition and relations with a non-Jewish woman only involves Rabbinic prohibitions (most likely).

According to the Chochmas Shlomo, however, if the man is being motzi zera in order to prevent himself from falling into temptation with a non-Jewish woman, that hotzas zera is not a waste and would be permissible.

Comment: Your reference in Even HaEzer, is regarding arayos and not regarding a non-jewish prostitute.

Comment: How can hotzoas zera not be levatala? You dont gets points for doing a mitzvah, if you do it by way of an aveirah!

Comment: @MarsSojourner I noted that point that arayos is more severe than a non-jewish woman in my answer. Levatala means "for no productive purpose." Being motzi zera for diagnosi of fertility problems is not considered "levatala" because the ultimate purpose is to help the couple of children.  Similarly hotzas zerah to be makayim the mitzvah of onah is not "levatala."  The whole point of the Chochmas Shlomo is that this hotzaas zera is not levatala and therefore not an aveira at all.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. If he has the choice then he has the choice to make a Golem like the Brothers (Yosef's haTzaddik's brothers) were doing, and by that time with the knowledge and fear required he'd come to his religious senses.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post an answer earlier but I figured I should check Otzar HaPoskim first. Unfortunately HebrewBooks only had volume one. So over Shabbos I popped into a shul that has the set. There was nothing there. Not even a mention of the B.Sh. and Ch.M. that @sam mentions in his answer. Very surprising. But I digress. Here's my thoughts.

Once upon a time I had the same diyuk as Sam gives in his answer. 
However, I think if we take into perspective the amount of enactments and safeguards Chazzal established to keep us away from having relationships with nonjews it would become very clear that having relations with a nonjewish lady can never be an option simply to avoid a different Rabbinic sin.

See the Mishna in Avoda Zara [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=35b&format=text) and the connected Gemara [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=36b&format=text). There were enactments against their cooked food, their bread, their oil, their wine. There were enactments to treat their children as Zavim and Zavos from birth. Seclusion with them is not allowed. The list is huge. Originally there was an enactment not to charge them interest so as not to affiliate with them so we wouldn't learn from their ways. We can't go to parties they invite is to even when there is kosher food. All to keep us away from them. There were never any special enactments instituted by Chazzal to make sure someone is not motzie zera livatala. At least not that I'm aware of. I think this should prove to us which one of these sins Chazzal were more worried about.

Comment: Isn't that regarding MARRIAGE and not just having relations

Comment: @hazoriz See the Gemara. Marriage is dioraisa, chashmonaim made a gezeira on znus. This was one option presented. But in any option the Gemara offers znus with a nonjewish lady is part of a bigger problem.

Comment: @hazoriz in case I wasn't clear, I'm not choosing one lashon in the Gemara over the others. I'm pointing out from all the enactments as a whole their involvement with this issue and the extra care they took regarding it.

Comment: are you not saying that because of one option you say that chazal was very strict regarding znus spesificly (and marriage)? (+1)

Comment: "very clear that having relations with a nonjewish lady can never be an option simply to avoid a different Rabbinic sin." Why? relations with a non-Jewish lady is not a biblical offense.

Comment: "There were never any special enactments instituted by Chazzal to make sure someone is not motzie zera livatala." Actually the rabbis were concerned lest a person even come to hirhur; lewd thoughts. They also were concerned with acts that may lead to a nocturnal emission; kal vachomer to doing so deliberately...

Comment: "I think this should prove to us which one of these sins Chazzal were more worried about." Even if your claims were true (which is not the case) your conclusion is still flawed. The fact that for whatever reason the rabbis did not enact safeguards around a particular sin and were "not worried about it", does not tell us which sin is preferable if a person must perform one.

Comment: @mevaqesh concerning your first question see my previous comments. Concerning your second, whatever they said to do so as not to transgress a sin which is possibly biblical but at the very least a rabinic injunction with an asmachta is till not a full fledged gezeira. And for your third point, you are entitled to your opinion. I offered mine after doing my due diligence researching.

Comment: According to many Rishonim including Tosafot and Ramban, ונשמרת is a full derasha. Accordingly, even hirhur is biblically forbidden. Even according to the disputants it is still likely fully rabbinicaly forbidden.

Comment: @mevaqesh that was my point. Even considering how chamur it is, we only find advice about how to sleep or where not to look etc, we don't find actual gezeiros concerning it.

Comment: If it is biblically forbidden to bring oneself to inadvertently ejaculate, then doing so deliberately would certainly be biblically forbidden, whereas relations outside of marriage with a non-Jew who is not a member of the 7 nations, would almost certainly not be biblical.

Comment: @mevaqesh again, as I mentioned in my answer, that was my knee jerk reaction as well. Just as Sam posits. However, Chazzal were very concerned about relationships with nonjews. They realized, based on pesukim that a relationship with a nonjewish is part of the step by step process to forsake ones religion. This is not the case with hotzaas zera. Imagine if you were aware of two individuals, each going to do one of the sins under question. Who would you stop if you could only stop one? Answer is the guy headed to the nonjewish girl. Because you know that his entire religious life is on the line

Comment: @user6591 But what if she is a non jewish prostitute? There is zero issue of marriage. I know that the Ramabam says that you cant have a goyyish girlfriend, but a once in a while occurrence cant be the same as having  a girlfriend.

Answer (score -2):

Probably wasting seed [NOT deliberately], because there, if it comes out against his will, so he is an ones. As opposed to deliberately doing something that is forbidden.

Comment: Seemingly the question was comparing cases where the sins were either all on the same level of intent.

Comment: +1 but that was not one of the opinions